# ADC input protection with a series resistor

Tags: microcontroller, adc, protection, piezo

I am trying to protect an [ATSAML22J18](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAM-L22-Family-Data-Sheet-DS60001465B.pdf) ADC input from sporadic piezoelectric sensor voltage spikes.
The piezo's typical output range is matched to the sensing application. The application makes it cumbersome to add all the components necessary to properly regulate the piezo's voltage, see [2](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa033a/sloa033a.pdf).

One piezo terminal is directly attached to VDD. For protection I plan to add resistance R in series between the other piezo terminal and the ADC pin.

- I observe spikes within 20 V hitting the piezo hard. Conservatively, the spikes are within 100 V.
  From the datasheet, max. input pin current injection is +/-1 mA in the most stringent case; I assume this is the current limit of the microcontroller's internal protection diodes.
  To protect the ADC, it is sufficient that 1 mA · R > 100 V. (See datasheet notes to Section 44.9).
- Input pin impedance is ~2 kΩ and sampling capacitance is ~3 pF.
  ADC minimum sample rate is 10 ksps (in fact the sensor only needs 100 sps).
  So for accuracy R must be such that (R + 2 kΩ)·(3 nF)·(9.7)<< 1/10e3 s. (See datasheet note to Table 44-26).

Both conditions hold by an order of magnitude when R = 1 MΩ. Is this reasoning sound and is it all I need to consider?

Comment: I don't see anything in [2] that suggests a problem with just slapping clamping diodes on it. What's your concern? Note that injected current on analog inputs will likely result in erroneous readings; the datasheet recommends such (p.1026-1027); other parts generally indicate 0mA injected, too.

Comment: The microcontroller isn't the constraint, it's the application. (sensorwatch.net) Adding and routing components on that part of the device is involved. Adding a resistor in series to the ADC pin is straightforward. It is much more difficult to add a component like a BAV99. Many sensing inaccuracies are tolerable; I am only trying to use the piezo to detect tap events.